# Getting the length of a 'named' array?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure what they are called, but what I mean is this:

```
array["water"] = 50;
array["fire"] = 30;
```

length should be 2 here

how can I see how many attributes I have in the array? array.length doesn't work =( I've been trying all kinds of things and I feel like I'm missing something really simple here..

Thank you for your help

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object.

Comment: @Juhana: I *could* be an Array, but [it should not](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to obtain an array of keys, then count them:

```
Object.keys(array).length
```

Or, if you're targeting ECMAScript 3 or otherwise don't have `Object.keys()`, then you can count the keys manually:

```
var length = 0;
for (var key in array) {
    if (array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        ++length;
    }
}
```

There are a few edge cases with this approach though, depending on the browsers you're targeting, so using [Mozilla's polyfill for `Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility) instead might be a good idea.

Comment: Woot, thank you. exactly what I needed, sorry for the trouble

Comment: @rid it might be better to do `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(array, key)` just in case `array` has a property `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @PaulS., well, there are quite a few more edge cases, but they're all handled by [Mozilla's polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility). Answer updated.